# Fill table in MSSQL automatically

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and i have an exercise where i have to populate some tables with 15 entries each. The ER model for my tables is here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Nv7FRWWX54dnRIUGNPR0U2WTg/edit?usp=sharing
This is how i created the tables

```
    CREATE TABLE Suppliers
             (sid INTEGER ,
              sAFM REAL ,
              sname CHAR(10) ,
              sstreet CHAR(20),
              stel REAL,
              PRIMARY KEY (sid))
CREATE TABLE Product
            (pid INTEGER,
             pname CHAR(10),
             pdescription CHAR(20),
             pprice REAL,
             pleft REAL,
             sid INTEGER NOT NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY (pid),
             FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Suppliers
                     ON DELETE CASCADE
                     ON UPDATE CASCADE)

CREATE TABLE Categories
             (ccid INTEGER,
              cdescription CHAR(20),
              pid INTEGER NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (ccid),
              FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES Product
                     ON DELETE CASCADE
                     ON UPDATE CASCADE )

CREATE TABLE Supply
             (ssid INTEGER ,
              sdate CHAR(8),
              squantity REAL,
              sid INTEGER NOT NULL,
              pid INTEGER UNIQUE,
              PRIMARY KEY (ssid),
              FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Suppliers,
              FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES Product
                     ON DELETE CASCADE
                     ON UPDATE CASCADE)
CREATE TABLE Customers
             (cid INTEGER ,
              cname CHAR(10) ,
              cAFM  REAL ,
              cstreet CHAR(20),
              ctel REAL,
              PRIMARY KEY (cid))
CREATE TABLE Often_Customers
              (cid INTEGER NOT NULL,
               ccredit_limit REAL ,
               cremainder REAL 
               PRIMARY KEY (cid)
               FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customers)
CREATE TABLE Payments 
              (cdate CHAR(8) ,
               cammount REAL ,
               cid INTEGER NOT NULL,
               PRIMARY KEY (cid),
               FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Often_Customers
                       ON DELETE CASCADE)
CREATE TABLE Places
              (gid INTEGER ,
               gname CHAR(10) ,
               gpopulation REAL ,
               sid INTEGER NOT NULL,
               cid INTEGER NOT NULL,
               PRIMARY KEY (gid),
               FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Suppliers,
               FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customers
                           ON DELETE CASCADE
                           ON UPDATE CASCADE)
CREATE TABLE Orders 
             (oid INTEGER ,
              odate_order CHAR(8),
              odate_send  CHAR(8),
              cid INTEGER UNIQUE,
              pid INTEGER NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (oid),
              FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customers,
              FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES Product
                              ON DELETE CASCADE 
                              ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Is there an easy way to do that instead of writing 15 insert commands for each table?

Comment: what database you use? mysql? oracle? postgresql?

Comment: fast way : php for with incremental variables. (or random one), u can also take a look in google: http://www.datanamic.com/datagenerator-for-mysql/index.html

Comment: i use MS sql server 2005

Comment: [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/). Although, for *15* entries, just enter them and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

the google drive link you shared requires login which is not a very good idea
to have in your question post

you can insert one row, then go to Ms Excel and paste it there
then expand it as a series to generate 15 rows and copy the remaining 14 rows directly

I am assuming you are trying to do it via SQL Server